# Debian Kernel Upgrade Issue

Tags: debian, linux-kernel

I have been trying to update the kernel (it's an OpenVZ VPS), but even though going through the procedure, `uname -r` returns `2.6.32-042stab132.1` and `hostnamectl` returns the following output now:

```
Failed to query system properties: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
```

So I have been doing the following:

```
$ sudo apt-cache search linux-image
linux-headers-4.9.0-9-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64
linux-headers-4.9.0-9-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.9.0-9-rt-amd64
linux-image-4.9.0-9-amd64 - Linux 4.9 for 64-bit PCs
linux-image-4.9.0-9-amd64-dbg - Debug symbols for linux-image-4.9.0-9-amd64
linux-image-4.9.0-9-rt-amd64 - Linux 4.9 for 64-bit PCs, PREEMPT_RT
linux-image-4.9.0-9-rt-amd64-dbg - Debug symbols for linux-image-4.9.0-9-rt-amd64
linux-image-amd64 - Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
linux-image-amd64-dbg - Debugging symbols for Linux amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-image-rt-amd64 - Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package), PREEMPT_RT
linux-image-rt-amd64-dbg - Debugging symbols for Linux rt-amd64 configuration (meta-package)
$
$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.9.0-9-amd64
$ reboot
```

As doing this didn't change anything, (`hostnamectl` returned kernel the old kernel version), I went as described [here](http://jensd.be/818/linux/install-a-newer-kernel-in-debian-9-stretch-stable). And that resulted in the above problem.

So, how can I actually update the kernel in the OVZ VPS instance?

Comment: Now I it's not Linux/2.6, but as shown here: https://virtuozzosupport.force.com/s/article/VZA-2019-036 . That seems to be Linux/4.7, or did I understand it wrong? But when I try to install gcc-7, it prompts that I require Linux 3.2 or later. I am quite confused right now.

Comment: it's virtuozzo 4.7, not linux 4.7. And yes it's linux 2.6: "based on the RHEL 6.10 kernel 2.6.32-754.14.2.el6". again: you cannot change your kernel. If you were using LXC, LXD, Docker, you couldn't change kernel either. Same here. So either manage to make whatever you need work with your kernel, or change provider's solution (eg: a real VM)

Comment: Seems like I'll have to achieve what I tried in different ways then, but still thanks for your help :)

Comment: Right, OpenVZ uses shared kernel, so you can only switch to a provider which gives you other types of virtualization.